# How to do pandas equivalence of SQL outer join without a key

Tags: python, join, dataframe, merge

In SQL, you can join two tables without a key so that all records of both tables merge with each other.  If `pandas.concat()` or `pandas.merge()` or some other pandas syntax supported this, it could help me with one step of a problem I am trying to solve.  I found an outer join option on the help documentation, but I could not find an exact syntax to do what I wanted (join all records without a key).

To explain this a little better:

```
import pandas as pd

lunchmenupairs2 = [["pizza", "italian"],["lasagna", "italian"],["orange", "fruit"]]
teamcuisinepreferences2 = [["ian", "*"]]

lunchLabels = ["Food", "Type"]
teamLabels = ["Person", "Type"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lunchmenupairs2, columns=lunchLabels)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(teamcuisinepreferences2, columns=teamLabels)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Outputs these tables:

```
      Food     Type
0    pizza  italian
1  lasagna  italian
2   orange    fruit

  Person     Type
0    ian        *
```

I want the final result of the merge to be:

```
  Person     Type Food     Type
0  ian        *   pizza     italian
1  ian        *   lasagna   italian
2  ian        *   orange    fruit
```

Then I can easily drop the columns I don't want and move to the next step in the code I am working on.  This doesn't work:

```
merged_data = pd.merge(left=df2,right=df1, how='outer')
```

Is there a way to do this type of `DataFrame` merging?

Comment: It looks like to me you are trying to do a `cross join` perhaps? In Python this can be done by doing, say, `vals=[(x,y) for x in list1 for y in list2]` non-Pandasically

Comment: I have one version of my code that does not use data frames at all.  It uses the data as lists and uses loops and list comprehensions to solve it.  I then got interested in the problem of what if I used SQL like joins on datframes to produce the data and output the result as a dataframe?  Working on the answer based on posts here so far and it is now looking promising.  But your comment is a useful bit of code to skin the cat differently (producing nested list output).  Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: I'm not yet aware of a `cross join` feature in Python via pandas, but will keep an eye on the thread!

Comment: cross join may be a different but related concept.  Check out the answer that I accepted on here.  It solves the actual question I was asking.  Thanks for your comment.  I just modeled something based on it to solve another part of the code I was working on.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible with `cross-join`, [introduced in Pandas 1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Simply run:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add a column to both dfs with a constant value,

```
>>>df1['joincol'] = 1
>>>df2['joincol'] = 1
>>>pd.merge(left=df2,right=df1, on='joincol', how='outer')
  Person Type_x  joincol     Food   Type_y
0    ian      *        1    pizza  italian
1    ian      *        1  lasagna  italian
2    ian      *        1   orange    fruit
```

then delete it afterward when you remove your other undesired columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better approach than the `while` method below, but this ought to do the trick:

```
df2_copy = df2.copy(deep=True)

# Basically repeat the same row in df2 until the lengths of the two dataframes are equal
while df2.shape[0] < df1.shape[0]:
    df2 = df2.append(df2_copy)

# Join on the indices of each dataframe ([0,1,2] to [0,1,2])
together = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2').drop_duplicates()

# Fill 'ian' down
together['Person'] = together['Person'].ffill(axis=0)

# Fill type2 down
together['Type_df2'] = together['Type_df2'].ffill(axis=0)
```

`together` is now:

```
      Food Type_df1 Person Type_df2
0    pizza  italian    ian        *
1  lasagna  italian    ian        *
2   orange    fruit    ian        *
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @EFT answer, I often need some combo of values and dates, solution below. Can easily be generalized.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['a','b']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-03-01',freq='1M')})
pd.DataFrame({'ticker':df1['ticker'].unique(),'key':np.nan}).merge(pd.DataFrame({'date':df2['date'].unique(),'key':np.nan}),on='key').drop('key',1)

  ticker       date
0      a 2010-01-31
1      a 2010-02-28
2      b 2010-01-31
3      b 2010-02-28
```